# SQL IF statements in VB

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, string

I need to know if this particular block of code will work, and if not, what i need to do to make it work. I'm doing touchy business and i'd prefer to have it right the first time.

```
strsql = "IF COL_LENGTH('orders','nosign') IS NULL" & _
         "BEGIN" & _
         "ALTER TABLE orders" >& _
         "ADD nosign bit;" & _
         "END"
```

Comment: Test on a backup of your database. Run it in a transaction, too, so you can roll it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need either a space or a carriage return line feed (vbcrlf) where your "&"s are.

I think this is what you'd want:
strsql = "IF COL_LENGTH('orders','nosign') IS NULL BEGIN ALTER TABLE orders ADD nosign bit; END"

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it would work, but I'm not 100%. Either way, I'd prefer `Information_Schema.Columns` for this.